# How can i convert a python dictionary with tuple keys to a pandas multi Index data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

I have a python dictionary with tuples as keys ex:

```
dict={('m1',17):4,('m1',12):2,('m1',1):5,('m3',11):4,('m3',17):15}
```

I want to convert it into a pandas data frame like this:

```
m1 17 4
   12 2
   1  5
m3 11 4
   17 15
```

I've tried the following:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(dict)
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
df3=pd.Series(dict.values(),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(dict.keys(), names=['site','id'])
```

However, nothing works.
(I also need to name the index columns and value column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex

d = {('m1', 17): 4, ('m1', 12): 2, ('m1', 1): 5, ('m3', 11): 4, ('m3', 17): 15}
data = DataFrame(
    data={'column_name': list(d.values())}, 
    index=MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples=d.keys(), names=['site', 'id'])
)
```

Comment: This almost works, but the column name of the values is in a different row from the column names for the keys.

Comment: That's just the way pandas displays it. The answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `Series`

```
s = pd.Series(d)
Out[198]: 
m1  17     4
    12     2
    1      5
m3  11     4
    17    15
dtype: int64
```